# Error when trying to create an XML of 2D list array with other variables

Tags: c#, xml, arraylist

I've been trying for ages to create an XML document to save a large list along with a 'length' and 'height' for use with a level editor that im making.

Below is the class used for the serialization

```
[Serializable]
public class Save
{
    public List<int>[,] grid { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
```

Below is what happens when i click the button to save

```
if (keybstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.O))
{
    savegame = new Save();

    savegame.grid = new List<int>[length, height]; //length and height are part of the main class, and determine how big the grid class will be, as well as how big the editor area is.
    savegame.grid = grid; //this grid is part of the main class. It is used to control what has been placed in the editor.

    savegame.length = length;
    savegame.height = height;
    SerializeToXML(savegame);
}
```

And here is the 'serializetoXML' class

```
static public void SerializeToXML(Save save)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Save));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("save.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, save);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

Every time i try to run the serilization process, if the list is included i get the following error:

> There was an error reflecting type 'programname.Save'.

Basicly, all i need it to do is write it into an XML, and then be able to load it later on.

```
List<int>[,] grid;

...
protected override void Initialize()
    {
...
 grid = new List<int>[length, height];
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                grid[x, y] = new List<int> { 0 };
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: I have found a way around the problem.

Since i cant use multidimensional arrays in serialization, i decided to create new arrays for each 'block type' which lists where on the grid these blocks occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put some effort and drill down through the nested tree of inner exceptions, you will see that the `Multidimensional arrays are not supported` by the `XmlSerializer`.

If it suitable, you can use

```
public List<List<List<int>>> grid { get; set; }
```

instead.

Comment: Oh... So how would I go about saving the 2D array if thats the case? Would my only option be something along the lines of splitting the list into multiple arrays for each row/column?

Comment: Do you have a list of matrix and want to serialize it?

Comment: I'm afraid im not 100% sure what your asking since i'm still kind of learning. If your asking if there are any matrices being used, then no.